# Run PPT in browser as a .ppt

Tags: powerpoint

I have seen a powerpoint presentation (ppt) somewhere online which was a .ppt file and it ran within the web browser. So no need for exporting to html, swf, etc and it was rather good quality when it came to images.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single presentation you can use Google Docs' presentation "Embed" feature (upload the ppt to Google Docs, then click Share...publish / embed).

For a systematic solution based also on this, I suggest taking a look at [Google Docs' API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
string ExportLocation = "C:\\Sample";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open("C:\\ScreenShots.ppt",
            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            MsoTriState.msoFalse);
ppApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = MsoTriState.msoFalse;  //Hiding the application; But it will be displayed always
try
{
    Slides objSlides = oPres.Slides;    //Getting all the slides
    for (int i = 1; i < objSlides.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string file = Path.Combine(ExportLocation, string.Format("{0}.{1}", objSlides[i].Name, "jpg"));
        oPres.Slides[i].Export(file, "jpg", 800, 600);
    }
}
finally
{
    ppApp.Quit();   //Closing the Powerpoint application. Sometimes it won't work too.
}
```

Comment: Where is the context to this answer. You've said try this code. Try this code in what? What does it do exactly?